# Where is Android Studio installed directory in macOS?

Tags: android, macos, flutter, android-studio

In the [Install Android Studio](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#install-android-studio) section of the Flutter setup instructions, there is a paragraph:

> Run flutter doctor to confirm that Flutter has located your installation of Android Studio. If Flutter cannot locate it, run `flutter config --android-studio-dir <directory>` to set the directory that Android Studio is installed to.

My question is, in my macOS, I don't know what directory my Android Studio is installed in.

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir <directory>
```

I list the directory `~/Applications/`, but it only displays `Chrome Apps`:

```
debo-MacBook-Pro:Applications debo$ ls ~/Applications/
Chrome Apps.localized
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: it's in a subdirectory of `/Applications`.  No `~` beforehand.

Longer answer: `~/Applications` is a subdirectory of your home directory (`~`) named "Applications".  It doesn't have any special meaning to macOS.

`/Applications` is a directory in the root directory (`/`) that is used for all of the applications that show up in Launchpad, including Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**DATA DIRECTORY OF AS**

It is under your library folder. If you completely want to uninstall it you have to delete AndroidStudio folder under Google. If you delete from Application is not delete basically because it setup stays under library. PFA.
[image: Android studio install directory]

Comment: That is the _data_ directory, not the _install_ directory.  You should at least clarify that this does not answer the question as asked.